# How to check whether script has failed

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I want to run all the `.sh` files in a directory and check whether they failed or not. If they failed, I need to re-run only the failed scripts.

Here is the command I use:

```
parallel -j0 exec ::: ./*.sh //command to run files in parallel
```

Can you tell how to check whether a script has failed and how to run only the failed scripts?

Answer (score 0):

`--retries` should work:

```
parallel -j0 --retries 2 ::: ./*.sh
```